# Django templating system: Is there a way to render None as ''?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Simple question: in django's templating system None is rendered as str(None).
Is there a way to override this behavior? Example use case:
I have an IntegerField that's set to None in some instance.
So when displaying it:

```
{{instance.number}}
```

Displays None. I know I can place an if there, but it really doesn't make any sense to me to show an user the None keyword (maybe because it's a spanish erp).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try template filter:

```
{{ instance.number|default_if_none:"" }}
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#default-if-none

Comment: As it seems, default_if_none is a better choice

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [firstof](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#firstof) tag:

```
{% firstof instance.number "" %}
```

but this will only work if you know that `instance.number` isn't zero, since it checks for falsiness, and zero is falsy.